# How to separate the relationship between mean and standard deviation, mean and coefficient of variation?

Tags: correlation, mean, standard-deviation, confounding, coefficient-of-variation

I have again a similar question related to my previous posts. Please consider the following scenario:

1. Mean and standard deviation of **A** are positively correlated.
2. Mean and coefficient of variation (CV) of **A** are negatively correlated (r= -0.2, P-value= 0.03).
3. Mean of **B** and CV of **A** are negatively correlated.
4. Mean of **B** and mean of **A** are positively correlated.

So, how can I separate the correlation of **3** from the confounding effect of correlation **1**?
Please help.

---

[image: So, here are all the relationships that I mentioned]

My question is how can I separate the effect of correlation between CV and Mean of variable A from the correlation between Mean of variable B and CV of variable A?

Is there a way to investigate the slope of these two above relationships and infer something?

Comment: Correlation does not imply confounding. Are you thinking of A as a cause of B, or vice versa? Or is there a different variable? Can you draw a causal diagram with all your variables present?

Comment: I have added the figure. I am interested in the last correlation (CV of var. A and Mean of var. B). But I am struggling to argue against those other correlations affecting it and also how the correlation between SD and mean of var. A is affecting the estimation of CV for var. A.

Comment: Try mitigating the relationship between the Pearson correlation coefficient  (a computed function of the mean) from the mean by considering alternate correlation measures, like one based on the median or even the mode in place of the mean. So, outliers still impact the mean but to a lesser extent the new correlation.

Comment: When I say "causal diagram", I mean a Directed Acyclic Graph, where you have an arrow from $A$ to $B$ if you are thinking of $A$ as a cause of $B.$ So you would draw $A\to B.$ Your figures are not causal diagrams.

Comment: OK. I understood. But is there a way that I can adjust the CV to reduce the dependency on the mean? Like, normalize the CV so there is no or very low correlation between CV and mean?

Comment: How are $A$ and $B$ causally related? Are there any other variables that might be causally related to $A$ and $B?$ Can you please draw a causal diagram?